# Change SVG path with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

Here is the SVG path:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="sss" viewBox="0 0 500 300">
  <path id="s3" d="M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70 Z"/>
</svg>
```

How can I change the `d` value?

Why does `alert(document.getElementById('s3').d);` give me `undefined`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Attributes can be set another way, using `setAttribute`:

```
document.getElementById('s3').setAttribute('d', "M 10,90 Q 100,15 200,70 Z");

alert(document.getElementById('s3').getAttribute('d'));
```

That seems to work.

There is a difference between attributes and properties. Attributes are set like `<elem attr='value'>` and properties are dynamically set.

For example, an input element will not change its attribute when entering something in it. The property, however, will change. So `.value` would return the correct result, whereas `.getAttribute('value')` would return the initial value as set with `value="something"`.

In your case, it's an explicit attribute and not a property. Hence, `.d` does not work whilst `.getAttribute('d')` does.

http://jsfiddle.net/Kdp4v/

Comment: It would be more useful to show how to mutate the paths than to put them in an alert..

Answer (score 30):

The `SVGPathElement` interface does not have a `d` property:

- http://objjob.phrogz.net/svg/object/101
- http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathElement

As others have said, you can access the data as a big ugly string by using the standard DOM 2 Core method available to all XML applications, `myPath.getAttribute('d')`.

*Note that while SVG elements are in the SVG namespace, SVG attributes are not; you should **not** use `myPath.getAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg','d')`.*

However, if you want an object-oriented representation of the path data, you want one of these attributes:

- [`pathSegList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGAnimatedPathData__pathSegList)
- [`normalizedPathSegList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGAnimatedPathData__normalizedPathSegList)
- [`animatedPathSegList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGAnimatedPathData__animatedPathSegList)
- [`animatedNormalizedPathSegList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#__svg__SVGAnimatedPathData__animatedNormalizedPathSegList)

All of these attributes give you a `SVGPathSegList`, which is an ordered list (not an array) of [`SVGPathSeg`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#DOMInterfaces) objects that you can enumerate using `numberOfItems` and `getItem()`.

Note that `SVGPathSeg` is a base interface inherited by the more specific objects you get back from `getItem()`:

- [SVGPathSegClosePath](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegClosePath)
- [SVGPathSegMovetoAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegMovetoAbs)
- [SVGPathSegMovetoRel](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegMovetoRel)
- [SVGPathSegLinetoAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegLinetoAbs)
- [SVGPathSegLinetoRel](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegLinetoRel)
- [SVGPathSegCurvetoCubicAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegCurvetoCubicAbs)
- [SVGPathSegCurvetoCubicRel](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegCurvetoCubicRel)
- [SVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticAbs)
- [SVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticRel](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticRel)
- [SVGPathSegArcAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegArcAbs)
- [SVGPathSegArcRel](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegArcRel)
- [SVGPathSegLinetoHorizontalAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegLinetoHorizontalAbs)
- [SVGPathSegLinetoHorizontalRel](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegLinetoHorizontalRel)
- [SVGPathSegLinetoVerticalAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegLinetoVerticalAbs)
- [SVGPathSegLinetoVerticalRel](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegLinetoVerticalRel)
- [SVGPathSegCurvetoCubicSmoothAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegCurvetoCubicSmoothAbs)
- [SVGPathSegCurvetoCubicSmoothRel](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegCurvetoCubicSmoothRel)
- [SVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticSmoothAbs](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticSmoothAbs)
- [SVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticSmoothRel](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#InterfaceSVGPathSegCurvetoQuadraticSmoothRel)

Here's what the usage might look like:

```
var segments = myPath.pathSegList;
for (var i=0,len=segments.numberOfItems;i<len;++i){
  var segment = segments.getItem(i);
  switch(segment.pathSegType){
    case SVGPathSeg.PATHSEG_LINETO_ABS:
      // segment is a SVGPathSegLinetoAbs object
      console.log( "Absolute Line To", segment.x, segment.y );
    break;
    case SVGPathSeg.PATHSEG_CLOSEPATH:
      // ...
    break;
    // see http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG11/paths.html#DOMInterfaces for constants
  }
}
```

Comment: Incidentally, the reason I want it, is because I'm about to embark on a Javascript solution for projective transformation of an SVG. I would prefer a fully SVG solution, but I can't think of one. I feel like you're a person to check with though. Can YOU think of a pure SVG way? (I can't see why SVG transformations don't just take a few more numbers. Homogenous 3-vectors to represent 2-points, and 3x3 matrices to transform them, would be perfect.)

Comment: I just realised that this uses a deprecated interface, and no longer works. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34352624/alternative-for-deprecated-svg-pathseglist and in particular "there will be a new API
https://svgwg.org/specs/paths/#InterfaceSVGPathData
and a polyfill for that
https://github.com/jarek-foksa/path-data-polyfill.js
as well as a polyfill for the old API
https://github.com/progers/pathseg
Also see the official chromium bug
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=539385 "

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getAttribute()`:

```
alert(document.getElementById('s3').getAttribute("d"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello to contemporaries with the same problem. I don’t know about how it be in 2011, but we now have [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) to solve such problems

```
document.getElementById('id').setAttribute("nameOfAttribute", "valueOfAttribute")
```

```js
let foo = () => {document.getElementById('btn').setAttribute("d", "M42,2.98v43.54c0,0.54-0.71,0.98-1.59,0.98h-7.08c-0.88,0-1.59-0.44-1.59-0.98V2.98 c0-0.54,0.71-0.98,1.59-0.98h7.08C41.29,2,42,2.44,42,2.98z M18.62,2.98v43.54c0,0.54-0.71,0.98-1.59,0.98H9.96c-0.88,0-1.59-0.44-1.59-0.98V2.98C8.37,2.44,9.08,2,9.96,2 h7.08C17.91,2,18.62,2.44,18.62,2.98z")}
```

```html
<style>
   svg{
   width: 25px; 
   height: 25px;
}
</style>
<svg viewBox="0 0 50 50"> 
   <path id="btn" d="M8.5,2.99v43.88c0,0.66,0.74,1.05,1.29,0.68l31.73-21.87c0.47-0.33,0.47-1.03,0-1.35L9.79,2.31 C9.25, 1.93, 8.5, 2.32, 8.5, 2.99z"/>
</svg>
<button onclick="foo()">change</button>
```